# how to install from source code on mac terminal

Tags: macos, installation, command-line

I'm trying to install a software named ["pigz"](https://zlib.net/pigz/) on mac . after downloading the source code, in terminal I go to the folder containing source code then I run `make`. when I try to install it with `sudo make install` I get this message

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

or when I try to install it with `brew`

```
brew install pigz
```

I get this error

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/pigz-2.4.catalina.bottle.ta
Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 1 seconds. 3 retries left.
Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 2 retries left.  
Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 4 seconds. 1 retries left.  
##O=#  #                                                                      
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: homebrew.bintray.com
Error: Failed to download resource "pigz"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/pigz-2.4.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading https://zlib.net/pigz/pigz-2.4.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> make CC=clang CFLAGS=
  /usr/local/Cellar/pigz/2.4: 7 files, 154KB, built in 4 seconds
```

since I'm very new to command line I really don't know what this means and what I should do
I would appreciate your help

Comment: Why compile it yourself if you could use [brew to install `pigz`](https://brewinstall.org/Install-pigz-on-Mac-with-Brew/)

Comment: when I try to install it with brew I get  error. I added the error message in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code that you're looking at, there is a `Makefile`. When you run the command `make`, it executes the first default rule that it sees within that file.

When you run the command `sudo make install`, it looks inside of the `Makefile` and looks for the `install` rule. However, if you look at the `Makefile` of the software you're looking at, there is no `install` rule, hence the reason you get the error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

This is simply because there is no rule to `install` anything, so when you run that command, it simply will not do anything.

You can get a better understanding of this stuff by searching online about what `Makefiles` are, you'll find a bunch of resources. [This](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/makefiles.html#:%7E:text=A%20makefile%20is%20simply%20a,files%20and%20the%20resulting%20executable.) can be a good starting point.

Comment: As the other guy mentioned, it might be easier to just `brew install pigz`. But, if you want to compile it yourself, you would first have to run `make` (since you already did some stuff, you can run a `make clean` first, this will remove all the things you did previously). After running `make`, you will see a `pigz` executable which was created within that directory. You can simply do `./pigz` to run the program from there on.